# How to get queue length in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code where I get the queue length, but on the browse method. How can I get the queue length, but on consumer via JMS? If not via JMS, then maybe via some other class from another package? I'm working with classes that are in the javax.jms package

```
QueueSession queueSession = null;
QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
QueueConnection connection;
connectionFactory = new ActiveMQQueueConnectionFactory("tcp://" + urlBroker);
connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection(login, password);
queueSession = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
QueueSession queueSession = new QueueSession

QueueBrowser queueBrowser = new QueueBrowser();
Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + queueName);
queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);

Enumeration<Message> messageEnumeration = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
            while (messageEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                messagesList.add(messageEnumeration.nextElement());
            }
System.out.println(messagesList.size());
```

In this case, do not read the messages, but simply put them in an arrayList using the Consume class. Or maybe there is a separate get method for consume to get the queue length

Answer (score 1):

The JMS API doesn't really provide a way to get the length of the queue as it's not something that a consumer should really care about. You can get an approximation of the queue length using a `QueueBrowser`, as you mentioned, but there's no way to do this with any other JMS API call.

If you really want to know the length of the queue then you can use the [management API](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#management) of ActiveMQ Artemis. There's a handful of different examples shipped with the broker that demonstrate how to use the management API in different ways.